# Why are the labels twitching vertically in TimelinePlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Why are labels jumping up and down here:

```
Dynamic[TimelinePlot[{{Interval@{Now, 
          Now + Quantity[2, "Minutes"]}}, {Interval@{Now + 
           Quantity[2, "Minutes"], Now + Quantity[5, "Minutes"]}}}], 
     UpdateInterval -> 0]
```

Comment: I don't know. But, watching the axis slide by is mildly creepy. :)

Comment: very similar issue: [80815](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80815/5478). Please report this to WRI.